# What is maximum limit of host for single NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, host, persistent-connection

We can add maximum concurrent connection per host in iOS using **NSURLSession**, [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407597-httpmaximumconnectionsperhost?language=objc)

How many different **hosts** can be added in NSURLSession concurrently to establish **persistent connection**.